# Angular Pipe with Subscription/Promise mess

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement an async Pipe
internally, the pipe is using a 3rd party component that returns a promise
Basically it looks up a dictionary and if key is found it returns the corresponding string value. If not found, it throws an error. I want to handle the not found part, and return a default value in that case. My problem is with this part - no matter what I tried, the result of the subscription is the error returned by the 3rd party component, no the value I return. Code is below:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'Lookup' })
export class LookupPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value: number, dataSource: BaseDataSourceAbstract, propName: string = "Text", sDefault: string = undefined, sNullValue: string = undefined): Observable<string>
    {

        //If default value was not set, set it to the original value
        if (sDefault == undefined && value != undefined) sDefault = `${value}`;

        //Get value
        var promise = dataSource.Store.byKey(value)
            .then(result =>
            {
                //If not found
                if (result == undefined) return sDefault;

                //Get result from the selected property
                var sReturn: string = result[propName];

                //Handle null
                if (sReturn == "" || sReturn == undefined) sReturn = sNullValue;

                //Finish
                console.log("Found: " + sReturn)
                return sReturn;
            })
            .catch(reject =>
            {
                console.log("Not found")
                return sDefault;
            });

        return from(promise);
    }
}



//use it:


   var x = new LookupPipe;
    x.transform(null, MyDataSource, 'Name').subscribe(s =>
    {
        console.log(s)
    });
}
```

I expect s to be my default value. I do see 'Not Found' in the console
But for some reason, s is the exception message that is returned from the byKey call

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud add a second callback function to the then:

```
p.then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
  }, function(reason) {
  // rejection
  // return your default value here.
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: I tried it, the result is the same. From what I understand from the documentation, having the 2nd callback is the same as having the .catch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something related to the 3rd party component. Solved it with them